# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is thrown when running an executable file

Tags: java, ubuntu, command, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and I am trying to run a Java program on the command line.

It is a program from a famous programming interview book, Cracking the Coding Interview, and the structure of directories and java files can be seen at

https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/tree/master/java

Here, I am running `Chapter 2/Question2_5/QuestionB.java`, and I use `LinkedListNode.java` class in CtCILibrary directory, and I also need `Chapter 2/Question2_5/PartialSum.java`

I went to `Chapter 2/Question2_5` directory, and compiled QuestionB.java using the compiling command

```
javac -cp .:../../CtCiLibrary/CtCILibrary/LinkedListNode.java ./PartialSum.java QuestionB.java
```

and it compiled(it took a while to figure out the compiling command), and made QuestionB.class file.

I ran `java QuestionB`, but it throws an error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: QuestionB (wrong name: Question2_5/QuestionB)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: QuestionB. Program will exit.
```

There were so many references when I looked up on Google, but none of them worked for me.

Can anyone tell me how to run this?

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means your classpath is broken.

Comment: That is what I have read when I looked up at Google. If you could specify where I am doing wrong, it would be much helpful. It's my first time running Java in command line, so I am really confused. (I only used c++ in command line/vim). Thank you.

Comment: Could you look up https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/tree/master/java/Chapter%202/Question2_5 and tell me how you would compile and run QuestionB.java in that directory? I checked out the top directory, so the structure of directories is exactly the same

Comment: You also need to specify a Classpath when running your compiled program.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what directory you were running the java command from.  since you did not specify the classpath the command it will look in the current directory (I believe) and down the classpath in the environment.  make sure that the file(s) are

- available on the classpath
- in directory appropriate for their package (if no package name then in the current directory)

Hope this provides some help.

Comment: I compiled and ran the program in Chapter 2/Question2_5 directory(I have stated it above)

Comment: it looks like your linked list class would not be on the classpath if you have done nothing to make it so.  the questionb class would need that to operate properly

Comment: Could you look up https://github.com/gaylemcd/ctci/tree/master/java/Chapter%202/Question2_5 and tell me how you would compile and run QuestionB.java in that directory? I checked out the top directory, so the structure of directories is exactly the same